# When should JavaScript anonymous functions be used instead of traditional named functions

Tags: javascript

For my example code below, the use of traditional named functions and anonymous functions perform the same task.

I've read [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname), and understand how the first named function is defined at run-time, whereas the second anonymous function is defined at parse-time for a script block.

My question is specifically what conditions would make one approach more suitable than the other?

```
function get1() {
    return 'Hello';
};

function alert1(data) {
    alert(data);
};

var get2 = function() {
    return 'Goodby';
};

var alert2 = function(data) {
    alert(data);
};


alert1(get1());

alert2(get2());
```

Comment: Don't forget you can have something like `var get2 = function get2() { return 'Goodby'; };` too which is useful for debugging.

Comment: When it makes your code more readable.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum.  Alma's duplicated post seems to say "always use them unless it makes your code less readable"

Comment: This is all about style and completely subjective

Comment: @user1032531 that's the same as what I said. Use them when it makes your code readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of a module I find it more readable to put any inner, utility functions defined such as `function logfoo` and `function logbar` *below* the return statement, and then rely on them being hoisted so that I can use them above/within the return statement.

```
var myModule = (function() {
    return {
        foo:  function() {
            logfoo();
        },

        bar: function() {
            logbar();
        }
    }

    function logfoo() {
        console.log('foo');
    }

    function logbar() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Not having to set a name for an anonymous function is just a
>   convenience thing since in most cases the name of the function doesn’t
>   really matter. Most of the time anonymous functions and named
>   functions will both do any job perfectly well.

Check this good article : [HERE](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/)